# Deezer gain property on track

Tags: deezer

We are trying to adjust volume to same volume level by using gain property on different tracks.

What is gain property on track? Max and min value? Is it possible/Is it good approach to adjust volume depends on gain property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good idea to use the property gain, it defines the signal strength.

The default value is 0, you can have lower and greater values that you will have to adjust around but I'm not sure that the method setVolume of the SDK will work fine with this value.

Comment: We have been testing it for several days and we found tracks with values equals 0 and below. The smaller number equals louder track. Are positive values quieter than tracks with 0?